# Directive with transclusion not using directive scope, even when specifically told to

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using a transcluding directive that, itself, is using a controller, that should redefine the inner scope, but isn't. And no matter how many tricks I use, I can't seem to get this done (leading me to believe I am doing something wrong).

The code is, reduced to a simple case, looking like this:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.1/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <mydirective>

    {{foo}}

  </mydirective>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
angular.module('app', [])

.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.foo = 'bar';
})
.controller('InDirectiveController', function($scope) {
  $scope.foo = 'baz';
})

.directive('mydirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    scope: false,
    template:'<div ng-controller="InDirectiveController">'+
                     '{{foo}} <inside></inside>'+
              '</div>',
    transclude:true,
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl, transclude) {

      transclude(scope, function(clone, scope) {
        element.find("inside").append(clone);
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Example here

http://jsbin.com/wuqoqalenu/1/edit?html,js,output

I would expect the output to be "baz baz", since I am specifically using transclude function. However, it is actually "baz bar", and I am not sure how to force the scope of the transcluded code to use the scope I am setting in the controller.

Comment: I have used 1.2.1 in the example, but with 1.3.1 it stays the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without replace:true, you essentially get the following for the directive HTML (before compilation)

```
<mydirective>
    <div ng-controller="InDirectiveController">
        {{foo}} <inside></inside>
    </div>
<mydirective>
```

When this is compiled, the directive scope remains the same as the outer (MainCtrl) scope, so the transcluded content is going to be evaluated against that scope.  Thus the first {{foo}} is "baz" (from InDirectiveController), and the transcluded content {{foo}} is "bar" (from MainCtrl).

With replace:true, the compiled directive HTML becomes:

```
<div ng-controller="InDirectiveController">
    {{foo}} <inside></inside>
</div>
```

When angular compiles this, ng-controller creates a new scope that inherits from MainCtrl's scope, which is associated with the directive's DOM node, so it becomes the directive's scope.  Thus, when you do the transclude, it is now using InDirectiveController's scope, so you get "baz baz".

UPDATE to address question from comment:

Directives don't always create new scopes.  When you use

```
scope: false
```

the directive scope will be the same as the "outside scope".  So when the link function for the directive runs, it will be the "outside scope".

The transclude function uses the scope passed as the first argument as the scope for the transcluded content.  In your first example, this scope is the scope passed into the link function, which in the first case will be the "outside scope".

When you set replace: true, this still doesn't cause a new scope to be created.  However, your template uses ng-controller on it's outer element.  Angular compiles by traversing "down" the DOM, and links by traversing back up.  So it compiles the directive, then compiles the template, and then links the template (calling ngController's link function which creates a new scope), and then the directive's link function with the scope of the directive's template element, which is now the scope created by ng-controller (rather than the "outer scope").

UPDATE:  Directive implementation without mg-controller

```
.directive('mydirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    scope: true,
    controller: function($scope) {
       $scope.foo = 'baz';
    },
    template:'<div>'+
                     '{{foo}} <inside></inside>'+
              '</div>',
    transclude:true,
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl, transclude) {

      transclude(scope, function(clone, scope) {
        element.find("inside").append(clone);
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for explaining what replace:true actually *does*, but I still don't get why is the scope different in each case. Why is in the first place the content evaluated with the outside scope, when I am using the link and transclude function? On many places, I have read that when using transclude function, it is evaluated with the directive's scope.

Comment: I've tried to amplify my explanation.  The transclude function uses whatever scope you pass in as the first argument, which in your case is the directive's scope.  What the directive scope "is" can change based on how you implement your directive.

Comment: Thanks! What exactly would happen if I used `scope: true` in my original example, without the replace? (PS : I feel like I am kind of abusing the template system and it's actively fighting me :), so I am not "doing it right" anyway)

Comment: I don't think scope: true would change things without replace: true.   Without it is an interesting question - I think the real problem is using ng-controller inside your directive.  This isn't "wrong", per se, but a better approach would be to just use the directive controller.  I'll add an example.  What output is "right" from your perspective?

Comment: What I am *actually* doing: I am taking code (not mine originally), that had in all the views (about 10) copied the same 4 controllers inside each other and some "wrapping" HTML elements. It's not possible to move it to `index` outside of `ng-view`. And I hate large pieces of code being copy-pasted throughout the code, so I wanted to move it to a single place, the place being the directive. (And nested views seemed like an overkill.)

Answer (score 0):

Adding `replace: true` somehow magically fixed it.

***I have no idea why***, but it did.

Example here

http://jsbin.com/muhomuxuse/2/edit

edit:

According to [angular documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile), "replace" parameter is being deprecated *and* should have no effect at all at scope inheritance. However, it has, and I am not really sure if it's a bug or a feature.